# How to add QGIS layer in ArcGIS jsapi?

Tags: javascript, qgis, arcgis-js-api

I'm using ArcGIS jsapi. It works well with ArcGIS MapServers, but I want to add QGIS layer.
I tried to use WmsLayer:

```
var map = new EsriMap("cgis-map", {
    logo: false,
    slider: false,
    lods: this._buildLods()
});
map.addLayers(this._buildLayers());

var wmsLayerInfo = new WMSLayerInfo({ name: "country", title: "QGIS Layer" });
var resourceInfo = {
    extent: extent,
    layerInfos: [wmsLayerInfo]
};
var wmsLayer = new WMSLayer("http://mrdata.usgs.gov/services/country", {
    resourceInfo: resourceInfo,
    format: "PNG24",
    transparent: true,
    version: "1.1.1",
    visibleLayers: ["country"]
});
map.addLayer(wmsLayer);
```

But it doesn't work.
How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide all the required properties for resourceInfo. Below is the list of all the properties. You are missing **getMapURL**

```
 String             copyright           
 String             description         
 Extent             extent              Required
 String             featureInfoFormat   
 String             getFeatureInfoURL   
 String             getMapURL           Required
 WMSLayerInfo       layerInfos          Required
 Number             maxHeight           
 Number             maxScale            
 Number             maxWidth            
 Number             minScale            
 String             title               
 String             version
```

Comment: **<String> - getMapURL - Required - The URL for the GetMap request. Required if the URL for the GetCapabilities is different than the URL for GetMap.**
(https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/wmslayer.html)

I added this and request was sent. Still layer does not drawn. I will find solution further. Thank you:)

Comment: The request has not **SRS** parameter. Without **SRS** I can't get map image. Request: http://mrdata.usgs.gov/services/country?LAYERS=country&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&WIDTH=1620&HEIGHT=950&FORMAT=image/png&BBOX=4410576.073543704,7077960.229100895,4624889.001763704,7203637.563550896&TRANSPARENT=TRUE